# How to loop through collection properties

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

I wan't show all users details in loop.
What i did, first getting the user info.

```
public function student($id)
    {
        $student=User::find($id);
        return view('profile-view',compact('student'));
    }
```

In my ***`view`*** i tried.

```
@foreach ($student as $key=>$value)
   @if ($loop->first)
     {{$student}}
   @endif
@endforeach
```

With this i'm getting this result:

```
{"id":1,"name":"raja","email":"raja@email.com","email2":"a@email.com","phone":"3213213211","phone2":"3213213211"}
```

I'm getting the **User Info** here.
But I wan't values only to be printed.

Comment: just change your `{{$student}}` to `{{$value}}`

Comment: `{{$value}}` results **1** that's it nothing else only result to screen is **`1`**

Comment: try looping the array of the student using `$student->toArray()` in you `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach ($student->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
   {{$value}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($student as $key=>$value)
    @if ($loop->first)
        {{$value}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```